# How to exclude time from date column

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

Hello Guys :) I have this little problem regarding C# syntax. this is my code

```
 listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] {dr["Date"].ToString() }));
```

This is the Output

[image]

And This Output is what i want where `Time` is not included

[image]

I tried this

```
lisView1.Items.Add(new ListviewItem(new string[] {dr["Date"].ToString("YYYY-MM-DD")}));`
lisView1.Items.Add(new ListviewItem(new string[] {dr["Date"].ToString("yyyy-mm-dd")}));`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `dr["Date"]` returns `object` which you cannot use overload `ToString` method of `DateTime`, so convert to `DateTime` first by using [`Field<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx) then use correct `DateTime` format `M/d/yyyy` in `ToString` method:

```
dr.Field<DateTime>("Date").ToString("M/d/yyyy");
```

You also can refer `DateTime` format in C# in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
lisView1.Items.Add(new ListviewItem(new string[] {dr.Field<DateTime>("Date").ToString("d")}));
```

MSDN describes most common string formats for date [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326721%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could also use the `GetDateTime` method on the `SqlDataReader`, and then call `ToString("M/d/yyyy")`, although you would then have to pass the ordinal for the column you're after, so the above answers are probably preferable.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetime.aspx